# Java ASN.1 validation library

Tags: java, validation, asn.1

Is there any free open-source java library to validate ASN.1 BER/DER/XER over [module definitions file](http://www.google.ru/search?q=DEFINITIONS+filetype%3Aasn).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are (Usually it is a part of encoder/decoder library) e.g.:

[JAC (Java Asn.1 Compiler)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jac-asn1/) is a tool for you if you want to (1)parse your asn1 file (2)create .java classes and (3)encode/decode instances of your classes.

Comment: I want to validate BERs on the fly at runtime. But as with JAC I'll need to generate java-files based on my asn-definition-file, then to try to decode my BER, and even then it will not take constraints into account. To my mind: JAC is raw enough project, that was written for some particular needs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use some of the [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) Classes for building this function.
Something that also might be usefull: [BERViewer](http://homepage.mac.com/aramperez/berviewer.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I saw, your propositions doesn't work with asn-definition-files.

Answer (score 0):

If your ASN.1 module definition file is not very big and if you just want to verify definitions are correct, you can use this online [tool](http://asn1-playground.oss.com/). To test your definition file you can decode either encoded binary data hexdump  or encode using ASN.1 value notation format of your type which is defined in your module definition file.